# Entity Framework: Connection String works in Main Project, but not in Test Project

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm using EF 6.0 code-first. In my application, I connect using a hard-coded connection string:

```
public class MyDbContext: DbContext
{
      // ...
        public MyDbContext(string connectionString):
            base(connectionString)
     {   }
}
var dbContext = new MyDbContext("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=SSPI");
```

This works just fine and I can access the database. In the unit-testing project, however, I connect using the same connection string and the connection fails when I first attempt to access some data:

> Format of the initialization string does not conform to specification
>   starting at index 0

Why does the same connection string work in the main project but not in the test project?

Comment: This error frequently occurs when the connection string is in an incorrect format... you might want to double check http://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: Thanks. The connection string is the same between both projects, and the connection works in one but not in the other.

Comment: Where are you calling the `var dbContext = new MyDbContext` line from?

Comment: how and where do you initialize your `dbContext`?

Comment: I'm calling this inside the two projects: in Main() for the main application, and in [TestInitialize] for the test project.

Comment: do you have any config file beside your projects with specified `connectionstring` section?

Answer (score 0):

The app.config was configured erronously.

The  section in both projects (main and test) looked identical, except for one item. The test project had an additional "parameters" section.

```
 <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
```

After removing the "parameters" section from the test project's app.config, the connection works fine.

Comment: I would delete that section entirely. I never have it in any of my projects!!! as long as you have the `<connectionStrings><add /></connectionStrings>`